# load external javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to download javascript files in parallel via injecting the script element and the src of the file in js like so

```
:javascript
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "/javascript/some_javascript_file.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript"
  $("head").append(script)
```

....
(using haml, jquery..)

in rails via firebug i get a 404 file not found which looks like this

GET http://localhost:3000/javascript/%5object%20HTMLScriptElement%5D 404 Not found

..i see that the other js files added via javascript_include_tag loading fine

GET http://localhost:3000/javascript/another_js_file.js?1221321321 ...

I know that rails adds a version number onto the js file for versioning. Is it not possible to load js dynamically like how i am doing for this reason? I also noticed that the script name is also obfuscated(%5object%20HTMLScriptElement%5D). Is there a rails way of doing this? I have looked online and could not find anything.

I just noticed that the url for the 404 is different from what i specified in the src. In the src i have "/rails/javascripts/javascript_file.js" but in the 404 error its listed as getting the file from http://localhost.admeld.com:3000/rails/some_namespace/%5Bobject%20HTMLScriptElement%5D

Edit:
The jquery getScript call worked.

```
$.getScript('/rails/javascripts/javascript_file.js', function(data, textStatus){
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log('Load was performed 0.');
});
```

Comment: Could you put the js code in application.js instead?

Comment: i will try using jquery's http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ call. It looks ruby mangles the src of the script somehow..?

Comment: jquery getScript call worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   :javascript
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "/javascript/some_javascript_file.js";
      script.type = "text/javascript"
      $("head").get(0).appendChild(script);
```

Comment: @aaron, You mean, even with the above you get the "obfuscated" thing? Then it is being manipulated somehow outside. Can you see what JS actually gets outputted to the browser from my answer?

Comment: yea from the change above, i still the 404 and mangled script name.